# magento 1.7 - can't remove discounts

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I created a catalog price rule that gave a 3% discount on all products.  Then I disabled the rule, but the discount still appeared. Then I tried changing the discount to zero and even deleting the rule. Discount still does not go away.  I waited a day thinking that discount was fixed by day.  Still no luck.  Last resort is rolling back to last week's backup.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to clear all cache and re-index after modifying the rules.